# Odd behavior of std::vector back()

Tags: c++, c++11, stdvector

The following code asserts in the indicated place with **"iterator+offset is out of range."**

```
void Network::PushInput(int c, int h, int w) {
    Input* input = new Input(batch, c, h, w, data);
    layers.push_back(input);    // this happens to be the first push_back()
//  layers.push_back(input);    // doing another doesn't change the assert!
    Layer *foo = layers.back();  // asserts here
    Layer *baz = layers[layers.size()-1];  // does not assert
}
```

Input is a public subclass of Layer. layers is declared as

```
std::vector<Layer *>layers;
```

If I attempt to duplicate the above with more vanilla template types, e.g., int*, back() works as expected with no asserts. Somehow, the template type matters here. (Note: _ITERATOR_DEBUG_LEVEL is 2, which triggers that assert check in the vector class.)

I'd rather not bluntly change all of the back()'s in the code to size()-1, but would rather understand what is going on here.

Any ideas? (I'll continue to perturb the code until I can find the apparent cause of this, but hopefully this will be obvious to someone else.)

(I'm using Visual Studio 2013 Community Edition, if that matters.)

.....

Here's a stand-alone file that compiles that shows the problem:

```
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

namespace layer {
    class Layer {
    public:
        Layer(float alpha = 0, float momentum = 0.9f, float weight_decay = 0);
        virtual ~Layer();

        // three virtual method that all layers should have
        virtual void forward(bool train = true) = 0;
        virtual void backward() = 0;
        virtual void update() = 0;

        void adjust_learning(float scale); // change the learning rate

        Layer* prev;                    // previous layer
        Layer* next;                    // next layer
        float* data;                    // X': output (cuDNN y)
        int batch;                      // n: batch size
        float alpha;                    // learning rate
        float momentum;                 // beta: momentum of gradient
        float weight_decay;             // gamma: weight decay rate
    };
} /* namespace layer */

namespace layer {
    Layer::Layer(float alpha_, float momentum_, float weight_decay_)
    {
        std::memset(this, 0, sizeof(*this));
        alpha = alpha_;
        momentum = momentum_;
        weight_decay = weight_decay_;
    }

    Layer::~Layer() {}

    void Layer::adjust_learning(float scale) {
        alpha *= scale;
    }
}

namespace layer {

    class Input : public Layer {
    public:
        Input(int n, int c, int h, int w, float* _data);
        virtual ~Input();
        void forward(bool train = true);
        void backward();
        void update();
    };

}

namespace layer {

    Input::Input(int n, int c, int h, int w, float* _data) : Layer() {
        prev = NULL;

        batch = n;
        data = _data;
    }

    Input::~Input() {
        data = NULL;
    }

    void Input::forward(bool train) {
        // nothing
    }

    void Input::backward() {
        // nothing
    }

    void Input::update() {
        // nothing
    }

}

using namespace layer;

namespace model {

    class Network {
    private:
        std::vector<Layer*> layers; // list of layers
        bool has_input, has_output; // sanity check
        float* data; // input on device
        int batch; // whole size of data, batch size
    public:
        Network(int batch_size);
        virtual ~Network();
        void PushInput(int c, int h, int w);
    };
}

namespace model {
    void Network::PushInput(int c, int h, int w) {

        Input* input = new Input(batch, c, h, w, data);
        layers.push_back(input);
        Layer *foo = layers.back();  // **WHY DOES THIS ASSERT??**
    }
    Network::Network(int _batch) {
        std::memset(this, 0, sizeof(*this));
        batch = _batch;
    }

    Network::~Network() {
        for (Layer* l : layers)
            delete l;
    }
}

void main()
{
    model::Network foo(10);

    foo.PushInput(2, 3, 4);
}
```

Comment: What does "asserts here" mean? What's the actual diagnostic? Is there a stacktrace?

Comment: The code, as shown, should work just fine. Is there something happening between the `push_back` and the `back` calls that you're not showing us? Please try to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and show it to us.

Comment: I emboldened the assert message that was in the first line.

Comment: `int*` is no more vanilla than `Layer*`, pointers are just pointers no matter how special the thing they point to.

Comment: @Pileborg: There's NOTHING else going on. Invoking back() immediately after the push_back() triggers the assert. I'll start subtracting code and look for what stops the assert.

Comment: @Dani: yes, I know. That's what's peculiar about this!

Comment: whats the relationship between class `Layer` and `Input`

Comment: @UpAndAdam: see the full example I included for details

Comment: Are you sure the assert happens in the `back` call, and not when the `Network` object is destructed?  Have you tried running in a debugger to catch the assert "in action" to locate it?

Comment: @Joachim: Yes, I'm single stepping through the code with F11. You figured out (indirectly) what the actual bug was: by zeroing out the Network instance with a memset, I apparently corrupted the vector variable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have *undefined behavior* in your code.

In the `Layer` constructor you do

```
std::memset(this, 0, sizeof(*this));
```

The problem with this is that the above call will clear the *virtual function table* (which is a part of the object) as well. Any virtual function called after that will not work as expected, if at all. That includes the destruction of the objects as the destructors are virtual.

Comment: It's actually the memset in the Network class that is the source of the problem! Commenting that out fixes the assert. Your comment fixes a separate bug in my code though! Thanks!!

Comment: @WaltDonovan Oh I missed that one, but yes that will cause problems too, as it will make the `vector` member all... "weird". :) The lesson here? Don't use C functions on C++ objects. :) Explicit initialization (preferably in constructor initializer lists) is the way to go.